# Scraping Data from Finviz using VBA. Code mostly working except for few small issues?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, web-scraping, element

Hi I have modified a VBA code to **scrape** data from the finviz screener. The code copies all the data in all the pages for the following 3 tabs: "Overview", "Valuation" and "Financial". Basically I have used the url for each of these tabs and copied the entire code 3 times with the column references changed.

The code works. However there are a few small things:

- Is there a way to not have 3 blocks of code but just one that changes the Tabs
- The column headers in the finviz tabs "Market Cap, P/E, Curr R etc" dont get copied in the first row of the excel spreadsheet
- There are 2 pieces of information: "IPO Date" and "Cash/share" that is not available in any of the tabs which I would also like. they can be found if I click on a single stock

```
Sub FetchTabularData()
        Const base$ = "https://finviz.com/"
        Dim elem As Object, S$, R&, oPage As Object, nextPage$
        Dim Http As Object, Html As Object, ws As Worksheet, Url$
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set Html = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
    
    Url = "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111"
    
    ws.Range("A1:E1") = Array("Ticker", "EPS", "EPS This Y", "EPS Next Y", "Price")
    
    R = 1
    
    While Url <> ""
        With Http
            .Open "GET", Url, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
            .send
            S = .responseText
        End With
    
        With Html
            .body.innerHTML = S
            For Each elem In .getElementById("screener-content").getElementsByTagName("tr")
                If InStr(elem.className, "table-dark-row-cp") > 0 Or InStr(elem.className, "table-light-row-cp") > 0 Then
                    R = R + 1: ws.Cells(R, 1) = elem.Children(0).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 2) = elem.Children(1).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 3) = elem.Children(2).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 4) = elem.Children(3).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 5) = elem.Children(4).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 6) = elem.Children(5).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 7) = elem.Children(6).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 8) = elem.Children(7).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 9) = elem.Children(8).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 10) = elem.Children(9).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 11) = elem.Children(10).innerText
                    
                    
                End If
            Next elem
            
            Url = vbNullString
            
            For Each oPage In .getElementsByTagName("a")
                If InStr(oPage.className, "tab-link") And InStr(oPage.innerText, "next") > 0 Then
                    nextPage = oPage.getAttribute("href")
                    Url = base & Replace(nextPage, "about:", "")
                End If
            Next oPage
        End With
    Wend
    
    
    Url = "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=121"
    
    'ws.Range("A1:E1") = Array("Ticker", "EPS", "EPS This Y", "EPS Next Y", "Price")
    
    R = 1
    
    While Url <> ""
        With Http
            .Open "GET", Url, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
            .send
            S = .responseText
        End With
    
        With Html
            .body.innerHTML = S
            For Each elem In .getElementById("screener-content").getElementsByTagName("tr")
                If InStr(elem.className, "table-dark-row-cp") > 0 Or InStr(elem.className, "table-light-row-cp") > 0 Then
                    R = R + 1: ws.Cells(R, 13) = elem.Children(3).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 14) = elem.Children(4).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 15) = elem.Children(5).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 16) = elem.Children(6).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 17) = elem.Children(7).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 18) = elem.Children(8).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 19) = elem.Children(9).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 20) = elem.Children(10).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 21) = elem.Children(11).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 22) = elem.Children(12).innerText
                End If
            Next elem
            
            Url = vbNullString
            
            For Each oPage In .getElementsByTagName("a")
                If InStr(oPage.className, "tab-link") And InStr(oPage.innerText, "next") > 0 Then
                    nextPage = oPage.getAttribute("href")
                    Url = base & Replace(nextPage, "about:", "")
                End If
            Next oPage
        End With
    Wend
    
    
    Url = "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=161"
    
    'ws.Range("A1:E1") = Array("Ticker", "EPS", "EPS This Y", "EPS Next Y", "Price")
    
    R = 1
    
    While Url <> ""
        With Http
            .Open "GET", Url, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
            .send
            S = .responseText
        End With
    
        With Html
            .body.innerHTML = S
            For Each elem In .getElementById("screener-content").getElementsByTagName("tr")
                If InStr(elem.className, "table-dark-row-cp") > 0 Or InStr(elem.className, "table-light-row-cp") > 0 Then
                    R = R + 1: ws.Cells(R, 23) = elem.Children(3).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 24) = elem.Children(4).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 25) = elem.Children(5).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 26) = elem.Children(6).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 27) = elem.Children(7).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 28) = elem.Children(8).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 29) = elem.Children(9).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 30) = elem.Children(10).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 31) = elem.Children(11).innerText
                    ws.Cells(R, 32) = elem.Children(12).innerText
                End If
            Next elem
            
            Url = vbNullString
            
            For Each oPage In .getElementsByTagName("a")
                If InStr(oPage.className, "tab-link") And InStr(oPage.innerText, "next") > 0 Then
                    nextPage = oPage.getAttribute("href")
                    Url = base & Replace(nextPage, "about:", "")
                End If
            Next oPage
        End With
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of repeating the code write a procedure like `Public Sub FetchTabularData(Url As String, StartColumn As Long)` so you can give the url and the column to start with as parameter and your code can be used for all 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of repeating the code write a procedure so you can give the variable things as parameter and your code can be used for all 3 times.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    ws.Range("A1:E1") = Array("Ticker", "EPS", "EPS This Y", "EPS Next Y", "Price")
    FetchTabularData "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111", 1, 11, 0
    FetchTabularData "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=121", 13, 10, 3
    FetchTabularData "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=161", 23, 10, 3
End Sub


Public Sub FetchTabularData(ByVal Url As String, ByVal StartColumn As Long, AmountOfColumns As Long, ByVal StartChildren As Long)
    Const base$ = "https://finviz.com/"
    Dim elem As Object, S$, R&, oPage As Object, nextPage$
    Dim Http As Object, Html As Object, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set Html = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
     
    R = 1
    
    ' deactivate screeupdating and calculation for speeding up
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Do While Url <> vbNullString
        DoEvents
        With Http
            .Open "GET", Url, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
            .send
            S = .responseText
        End With
    
        With Html
            .body.innerHTML = S
            For Each elem In .getElementById("screener-content").getElementsByTagName("tr")
                If InStr(elem.className, "table-dark-row-cp") > 0 Or InStr(elem.className, "table-light-row-cp") > 0 Then
                    R = R + 1
                    
                    ' prepare an temporary array to write the row data into
                    Dim TempRow() As Variant
                    ReDim TempRow(1 To 1, 1 To AmountOfColumns) As Variant
                    
                    Dim i As Long
                    For i = 0 To AmountOfColumns - 1
                        ' instead of writing to the cells directly
                        ' ws.Cells(R, StartColumn + i) = elem.Children(StartChildren + i).innerText
                        ' we write into the temp array
                        TempRow(1, i + 1) = elem.Children(StartChildren + i).innerText
                    Next i
                    
                    ' and write the entire row at once (10 times faster than writing each cell)
                    ws.Cells(R, StartColumn).Resize(ColumnSize:=AmountOfColumns).Value = TempRow
                End If
            Next elem
            
            Url = vbNullString
            For Each oPage In .getElementsByTagName("a")
                If InStr(oPage.className, "tab-link") And InStr(oPage.innerText, "next") > 0 Then
                    nextPage = oPage.getAttribute("href")
                    Url = base & Replace(nextPage, "about:", "")
                End If
            Next oPage
        End With
    Loop
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This could also be possible with the other For Loops nested into a main for loop to keep track of the URL's being used - `For f = 1 to 3 . . . . if f=1 then URL="url1" . . . if f=2 then URL="url2" . . . "if f=3 then URL="url3" . . . do the stuff with all the URL's.`  however, I _**REALLY**_ have begun to love making smaller routines to do a bit more work because then it becomes PORTABLE!  Nice stuff!

Comment: @k1dfr0std not possible because of the amount of columns changes with the urls too, so I see no space for optimization of calling `FetchTabularData` multiple times.

Comment: That's a great point - yeah - that's not easy to simplify at all.

Comment: That works perfectly. I didnt know how to do it within the same code due to the different number of fields. The column headings are still not being populated. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Mafoola Please note that we can only handle one question per post. See [ask]. So I suggest you mark this one as solved and open up a new question where you show how you tried to get the headings and focus on that question only, with a good description of where you got stuck in what you tried.